# Append ListBuffer with tuple

Tags: list, scala, listbuffer

I have several values that i am reading from simple `Text file`.

This is my data:

```
val data = new ListBuffer[(String, BigDecimal)]
```

Now i want to append items inside my `ListBuffer`:

```
data += ("bla bla", 12)
```

And then error received:

> type mismatch;  found   : List[(String, scala.math.BigDecimal)] 
>   required: (String, BigDecimal)
>           data += List(("bla bla", 12))

Comment: Try like this: `data += (("bla bla", 12))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To append it as tuple you should enclose it in parenthesis like this:

```
data += (("bla bla", 12))
```

Or you could use `append` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `append` function to achive this, e.g.

```
scala> val data = new ListBuffer[(String, BigDecimal)]
data: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String, BigDecimal)] = ListBuffer()

scala> data.append(("bla bla", 12))

scala> data
res11: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String, BigDecimal)] = ListBuffer((bla bla,12))
```